How I can dynamically create a variable number of interactive reports/charts in Oracle APEX?
In my application, as a part of creating a ‘a new project’, I allow end-users to select certain sites from a shuttle and store those in another table. In this way, one project can encompass one or more sites. What I am struggling to do is plot certain data for those sites in another page that contains the project info. For example, if for project 1 the end-user selects sites A, B and C I would like to have either a tabular or graphical visualization for key data for each site. So for each site perhaps I would have a table that contains a summary of basic stats for that site or perhaps a plot that depicts cumulative use of that site over the years.
My main question is, how can I use APEX to create a variable number of graphs or interactive grids/reports based on data that is present in a table? If a project as one associated site, I would expect one site/table, if two then two, etc.
Thank you

I don't think that you can do that absolutely dynamically, letting software do everything for you.
However, if we presume that there's a definite number of regions to be rendered, then here's one option.
Sample table (based on Scott's sample schema; it'll contain jobs):
create table sh_jobs (id number generated always as identity,
                      jobs varchar2(50));

Create an interactive grid region; jobs column is a shuttle item:

In order to be able to proceed with this task, create a view that normalizes data stored within the table:
create or replace view sh_jobs_v as
select id, 
  regexp_substr(jobs, '[^:]+', 1, column_value) job,
  column_value rn
from sh_jobs cross join 
  table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
                      connect by level <= regexp_count(jobs, ':') + 1
                     ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

View contents is then e.g.
SQL> select * from sh_jobs_v;

        ID JOB                                                        RN
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------
         1 ANALYST                                                     1
         1 CLERK                                                       2
         2 MANAGER                                                     1
         2 SALESMAN                                                    2
         2 ANALYST                                                     3

The next step is to create item which lets you select stored data; I put everything onto the same page, and this is just a simple select list item which also redirects and sets value (you can also submit, if you want; the key is to refresh the page):

Then, create that definite number of different regions. I chose classic and interactive report and interactive grid; you said you'll create charts and whatever else you want. I set 3 regions into the same row. Each of them contains server-side condition which decides whether to render it or not.

Run the page, enter some rows into the interactive grid, then select one of stored values and see the result. For example:


That's all; I showed you how to make it work. Now you can make it fancy.
